# Memory Leak when setting a List View Item to collpased

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I am developing a small log reader tool in WPF (.net core 3.1)

Log lines are collected and added to a class which inherits ObservableCollection

I am trying to add a filter to my log line (by matching an input regular expression).

I have added a property (bool IsVisible), to the log line view model,
which I'm setting to True / False, according to the line text match against
the input pattern.

I'm using a Data Trigger, to convert the IsVisible view model property into
the List View Item Visibility property (True maps to Visible, False maps to Collapsed)

This is causing a horrible memory leak, and the application is frozen. However, when
I change the mapping of False from Collapsed to Hidden, then application works just fine,
and no memory leak seems to occur (but it's looking really bad, because the Hidden lines
just vanish, which is just ugly).

Memory Leak:

```
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
```

No memory leak, but looking bad:

```
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
```

I just tried it with setting the Foreground color, instead of the Visibility, and it works fine (still not the prettiest, though). Surprisingly, the memory does climb up a bit, but remains stable, and UI is responsive.

```
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue" />
                            </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: What do you mean by " horrible memory leak"? Also if application is frozen means some work blocks UI thread, get a profiler and look what function is called on the UI thread and why it works for so long.

Comment: The memory is climbing up to around 2GB in no time, and, suppose that's right, and there's a UI blocking code, why is it invoked only when I'm mapping the Visibility property to Collapsed (and not when I"m mapping it to Hidden)?

Comment: Profiler will answer you why, profiler is your best friend :) Or you asking the comunity to profile this code instead of you? :)

Comment: I have already profiled this code, and could see nothing, besides tons of framework objects in memory. That's precisely why I'm asking the community to help me figure out why WPF is leaking memoery, when I'm simply replacing Hidden with Collapsed